exclude DirectoryIndex file from basic authentication
I have a Linux server running Apache httpd 2.4. I want the real name of the server (say real.example.com) to be used for administrative content (server-status, metrics, etc), and an alias (app.example.com) to host the end-user application-specific content (authenticated via LDAP).
For reasons, I'm trying to keep all the end-user content in a single flat directory (/path/to/app/files/). With the configuration shown at the bottom of this post, requesting https://app.example.com resolves to https://app.example.com/, which shows the contents of /path/to/app/files/index.shtml after the basic authorization challenge.
However, I want to isolate the entry "portal" page index.shtml from the authorization, i.e. https://app.example.com still shows the contents of index.shtml, but no authentication is required. Meanwhile, the links on that page all go to files in the same directory, and I want the user to be authenticated when initially requesting one of those, not before.
BTW, the reason for index.shtml is to include a message-of-the-day via <!--#include file="motd.txt" -->.
If I add Files as shown:
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/app/files"
    ServerName app.example.com
    <Files "index.shtml">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    <Files "motd.txt">
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</VirtualHost>

... and request just https://app.example.com, as I expect users to do, I still get the login challenge immediately, and then the contents of index.shtml (and motd.txt) are shown. But, if I explicitly request https://app.example.com/index.shtml (in a new instance of the browser), I get no login challenge, as desired, and clicking a link does pop up the challenge.
What else can I try? I tried adding DirectoryIndexRedirect on to the dir_module section, but it didn't change the behavior. (One silly reason for all this is to keep the portal URL as clean and short as possible, i.e. I am trying to avoid showing "index.shtml" in the URL. Another reason is to display login instructions on the portal page, which cannot be added to the browsers' challenge popup.)
<Directory />
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI +Includes
</Directory>

<Directory "/path/to/admin/files">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI +Includes
    AuthType none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/path/to/app/files">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI +Includes
    AuthType basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    Require valid-user
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.shtml
    # DirectoryIndexRedirect on
    DirectorySlash On
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/admin/files"
    ServerName real.example.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile    ...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/app/files"
    ServerName app.example.com
</VirtualHost>

